# Hanging something from an indoor window frame (drywall)

Tags: drywall

I have a pic that I want to hang up in an indented window frame (on the ceiling) so that the hook is at the bottom and I can hang the item from the hook.

I keep on running into drywall all over the top window area which just creates holes.  I can't seem to find any studs for the one screw, so what do I put there to hold the item firmly (it is not too heavy).

I've seen pics of the drywall hooks but by looking at them can't figure out how I would get it in there.  I could hang it from the side walls, but it seems much to complicated to do that as it's made to hang from one chain in the middle!

Are those other things easy to install?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a toggle bolt. It should easily support your hook.

Comment: Isn’t that 50 lbs. in shear, not withdrawal? I don’t think I understand how it’s mounted. If it’s mounted on ceiling, it’d be in withdrawal. If it’s withdrawal, it would need some kind of molly bolt.

Comment: Yeah, I misread that. Edited

Comment: The hook isn't all that needs to be supported. You have no idea what the frame and glass weigh, so this is risky advice. You're relying on the number of screws the drywall hangers put in the top of the window opening.

Comment: The item is light; I had a screw in at one time at an angle so that at least it was strong enough to hold something w/o falling.  Now, it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

For drywall the standard solution is a Molly bolt:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J2yNhDdZRak

You don't need the setting tool, simply drive the screw until you feel resistance, this means the metal fastener has expanded. Don't screw it too tight. If you want to remove it, keep driving the screw hard until the fastener breaks, and it will fall off. It's really easy to use and robust. Molly bolts are quite robust, I use them often. There are plastic versions, not worth the hassle IMO. Note: you must buy the proper type depending on the thickness of your drywall (if you have one or two sheets of gyproc on your wall, the fastener needs to be of the proper length).

However if this is just a very light picture frame (say a few hundred grams) to hang it on a wall you can just put a drywall screw directly into the drywall, at a 45° angle. It's fragile but it'll hold your picture frame just fine. (Don't do this on the ceiling though).

Comment: I guess I'm not too familiar with a toggle or Molly bolt (how to install) but I have saved the video.  I took a picture of the bathroom indented window frame but not sure how to send the picture to you (but I have it).

I have a variety of screws where I attempted to screw in the side with the threads into the ceiling (there are no other window treatments there).  But, the hook just goes in and leaves a hole and it is not entrenched into the wall to hold anything.  The screw part needs to be upside down to carry a small, lightweight panel. (for now, how do I post a photo?).

Comment: @TrudiNeiverth edit your question, click on the picture icon (or put a link in the comments)